# Can we setup VPC for AWS Lightsail resources?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-lightsail

I am developing an app and to host backend system I am using AWS Lightsail. Is there a way to keep all the inter service communication private?

I am aware this can be achieved with VPC while using AWS outside lightsail. Is there a way to setup Lightsail resources in VPC?